# Ginger bug, white powder kind of stuff on top

Tags: fermentation, ginger-beer

I just made a Ginger bug, feed Ginger and sugar daily, during first 3 days it was perfect with bubbles forming, but on forth day, no bubbles seen and some white powder/coat  kind of substance on top of bug and on edges of bug.
When picked by spoon and rubbed on finger it kind of dissolves, even when shaken and stirring it dissolved in the bug.

Do any of Friends have knowledge what is it, is in mold or fungus of any type, should I continue with it out throw it away.

Comment: Throw it out. It's mold.

Answer (score 1):

I think I made a good Ginger bug, just sharing my experience :-
Use air tight container, initially I used cloth to cover the container which might have lead to developing mold/yeast. But then I transferred it to an air tight jar, then it went okay and fermented it for 10 days without any molds/yeast.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably mold. Have you tasted the bug yet? Some molds just form on the surface (probably because they need oxygen) and can be removed, or just allowed to fall to the bottom over time. They don't affect the flavor or safety of the drink. Other molds ruin the flavor of the drink. I'd give the bug a taste and decide what to do next.

Do you use an airlock when ferementing the Ginger bug? That would help protect it from airborne molds and bacteria.

Comment: Thanks, I removed it and further it went all okay.i  Think it could have been a kahm yeast, just guessing.